# Select all <li> that don't have a checked checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, checkbox

I have a list of `<li>`s with a checkbox within each, and I want to hide all the `<li>`s that don't have a checkbox that is checked.

Currently I'm doing it by first hiding all `<li>`s and then unhiding the ones that have a checked checkbox, like this:

```
$("#categoryList").find('li').each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("searchhide");
});

$("#categoryList").find("input[type=checkbox][checked]").each(function () {
    $('#id-' + $(this).attr('rel')).removeClass("searchhide");
});
```

But isn't it possible to do it in a more straightforward way, by only hiding those which need to be hidden in the first place?

```
 $("#categoryList").find('li').not("input[type=radio][checked]").each(function () {
     $(this).addClass("searchhide");
 });
```

Comment: even more simple see my code...! ;)

Comment: @aSeptik Not simpler, just crammed into one line and less-readable `;)` (and [slower](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/#entry-longdesc), see additional notes...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#categoryList li > input[type="checkbox"]')
    .not(":checked")
    .parent()
    .addClass("searchhide");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function for this purpose;

```
$('ul li')
    .filter(function() {
        return $(this).find('input:checked').length == 0;
    })
    .addClass('searchhide'); // or .hide()
```

It simply selects all `li` elements and filters the collection to only include those who contain an unchecked `input` element.

Made this simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/st3fan/tSxyy/1/) to demo the function.

Including the related HTML;

```
<ul>
    <li>A <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></li>
    <li>B <input type="checkbox" /></li>
    <li>C <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></li>
    <li>D <input type="checkbox" /></li>
    <li>E <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></li>
    <li>F, li without a checkbox</li>
    <li>G, multiple checkboxes
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li>H <input type="text" value="text field" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That filter doesn't quite work, since it will hide a `<li>` which contains *any* `<input>` which is not checked. You probably want `return $(this).find('input:checked').length === 0;`. OP wants to hide `<li>`s which don't contain any checked checkbox.

Comment: @nbrooks There is a differens between "all <li> that have an unchecked checkbox" and "<li>s which don't contain any checked checkbox" but I still recommend the filter function.

Comment: Yes, there is a difference, and the desired result is the latter of the two (admittedly there was some ambiguity in the question title, but the text was clearer). You should only hide `<li>`s which don't contain a checked checkbox. Your code would even hide `<li><input type='text' /></li>`, because the text-box doesn't match `:checked`.

Comment: OK, that was a bit confusing but I adjusted the filter conditions in my answer. BTW: Even your own answer only hides/adds a class to `li` elements containing an unchecked checkbox `input`. However, the OP seems satisfied enough...

Comment: Ah, that's true...overlooked that somehow `:)`. Oh well, it seems to have been sufficient. +1 for your answer

Answer (score 0):

**demo**: http://jsbin.com/usepob/2/

```
 $('#categoryList li :checkbox:not(:checked)').parent().addClass("searchhide");
```